# Migration failure: Aborting migration: Timeout to receive migration response has expired

Tags: java, agents-jade

I am novice to JADE ,while trying to send mobile agent to remote side i am getting an error MIGRATION FAILURE .Even after searching on web i couldn't figure out what is causing such an error .Please sort this out .

This is how i am trying to send mobile agent

```
AID remoteAMS = new AID("ams@192.168.2.7:12345/JADE", AID.ISGUID);
remoteAMS.addAddresses("http://vishnu-PC:7778/acc");                             
PlatformID destination = new PlatformID(remoteAMS);
agent.doMove(destination);
```

Comment: Please someone help me out.

Comment: PLease help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Hello stackoverflow can anyone sort this out  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey after searching out myself as community didn't help i found out myself the following way:-

```
 IPMS version required was 1.2 for JADE 4.3.2
```

And the the following command was to be set using cmd for the platform where i wanted to send the mobile agent

```
 -services     jade.core.mobility.AgentMobilityService;jade.core.migration.InterPlatformMobilityService -accept-foreign-agents true
```